# Draw ontop of all views

Tags: android, draw

Is there a way to draw ontop of every view (like a watermark that shows everywhere for example)? sort of how the Dock4Droid app draws a a dockbar ontop of every screen.

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this. This app does something similar: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bb.microcpu and there are others.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to have a relative layout as your top level container. The very last item in your markup should be an imageview containing your watermark which you can then position on the screen anywhere you like.

Comment: But I do not want to tie this to just my activity, but the current active screen. IE if you go to Maps or Gmail, the watermark / overlay would still show.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can do your own drawing (onDraw) and set the opacity value such that it gives the presentation of being translucent.  Works for me with several of my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, as android app drawing is effectively sandboxed.

Even if you could, why would you want to? It seems like a major annoyance for your users. I know I would uninstall an app that did that.